# Automate the start/stop VMs during off-hours in Azure using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-automation, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to automate the start/stop VMs during off-hours in **Azure** using **Terraform**. This is the way of automating it in Azure portal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management I have done it once in azure portal but I want to do the same using terraform.
I've searched days to find out how to do this. I've found the same question asked by someone else before [Create Azure Automation Start/Stop solution through Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651326/create-azure-automation-start-stop-solution-through-terraform) but there was only one answer to that which is it's not possible since the Microsoft solution requires parameters on the runbooks, and there isn't any attributes in the provider to add parameters. But I'm not quite convinced with the answer.

I'm newish in Terraform and I know some resources like `azurerm_automation_job_schedule` and `azurerm_automation_runbook` must be used, but I couldn't figure out the whole module to do this. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: why using terraform when simple azure cli command can solve your issue? keep it simple

Comment: I can't. We have many VMs running on Azure for different projects and I'm doing this to reduce costs on them.The whole procedure should be automated using Terraform.

Comment: hi, I'm looking to do the same, did you find something ?

Comment: looks like the answer to the previous same issue is right; It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the post is a bit old now but I am responding if this is going to help someone trying to figure out the solution to pass parameter for the runbook. You can pass the required parameter in this resource provider "azurerm_automation_job_schedule". Please note the Parameters attribute this is how we can pass the required parameter. You can refer this link for more details.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/automation_job_schedule

```
resource "azurerm_automation_job_schedule" "startvm_sched" {
  resource_group_name     = "IndraTestRG"
  automation_account_name = "testautomation"
  schedule_name           = azurerm_automation_schedule.scheduledstartvm.name
  runbook_name            = azurerm_automation_runbook.startstopvmrunbook.name
   parameters = {
    action        = "Start"
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_automation_schedule.scheduledstartvm]
}
```

[image]

Below is the complete code for VM Start/Stop job schedule resource provider "azurerm_automation_schedule" and "azurerm_automation_job_schedule"

```
resource "azurerm_automation_schedule" "scheduledstartvm" {
  name                    = "StartVM"
  resource_group_name     = "IndraTestRG"
  automation_account_name = "testautomation"
  frequency               = "Day"
  interval                = 1
  timezone                = "America/Chicago"
  start_time              = "2021-09-20T13:00:00Z"
  description             = "Run every day"
}

resource "azurerm_automation_job_schedule" "startvm_sched" {
  resource_group_name     = "IndraTestRG"
  automation_account_name = "testautomation"
  schedule_name           = azurerm_automation_schedule.scheduledstartvm.name
  runbook_name            = azurerm_automation_runbook.startstopvmrunbook.name
   parameters = {
    action        = "Start"
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_automation_schedule.scheduledstartvm]
}

resource "azurerm_automation_schedule" "scheduledstopvm" {
  name                    = "StopVM"
  resource_group_name     = "IndraTestRG"
  automation_account_name = "testautomation"
  frequency               = "Day"
  interval                = 1
  timezone                = "America/Chicago"
  start_time              = "2021-09-20T10:30:00Z"
  description             = "Run every day"
}

resource "azurerm_automation_job_schedule" "stopvm_sched" {
  resource_group_name     = "IndraTestRG"
  automation_account_name = "testautomation"
  schedule_name           = azurerm_automation_schedule.scheduledstopvm.name
  runbook_name            = azurerm_automation_runbook.startstopvmrunbook.name
  parameters = {
    action        = "Stop"
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_automation_schedule.scheduledstopvm]
}
```