# Terraform - how to disable azure automation schedule

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-automation

How do I disable an azure automation job via terraform?  I have all the resources defined/applied via terraform, and when I disable the schedule via UI, `terraform plan` does not show any changes and I cannot find a property in any of the documentation.

[image]

Could not find anything in `azurerm_automation_schedule` or `azurerm_automation_job_schedule` unless I missed it?

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to disable the azure automation schedule in my environment and got the related results*

> It is not possible to disable the automation schedule using terraform there is no arguments supported to disable the scheduler

This [URL](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/automation_schedule) says there is no arguments to disable the automation scheduler while creating the scheduler itself automatically enable the scheduler

But I can able to start or stop the scheduler job automation  using terraform, this [@stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651326/create-azure-automation-start-stop-solution-through-terraform) will be help

The following example will create the schedule with in the automation account using PowerShell

```
New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "tfex-automation-account" -Name "Schedule01" -StartTime "23:00" -OneTime -ResourceGroupName "tfex-automation-rg" -TimeZone $TimeZone
```

[image]

When I open the portal and check the scheduler I can able it is enabled

[image]

By using the below command I can able to disable the automation scheduler

```
$automationAccountName = "tfex-automation-account"
$scheduleName = "tfex-automation-schedule"
Set-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName `
-Name $scheduleName -IsEnabled $false -ResourceGroupName "tfex-automation-rg"
```

[image]

When I open the portal and check the scheduler it is disabled

[image]